# Why does 100% height work inside a display:table-row on Chrome & FF but not in IE9?

Tags: html, css

I have a little dilemma. I could work around this issue, but it would be a pain to do so and still limit things in sense of how a site layout could work. Basically I've been using the following method to give myself a sticky footer that is actually height variable:

http://pixelsvsbytes.com/blog/2011/09/sticky-css-footers-the-flexible-way/

**Example:**

The CSS:

```
html, body {height:100%; width:100%; margin:0;}
.wrapper {display:table; width:100%;}
html>body .wrapper {height:100%;}
.wrapperRow {display:table-row;}
.wrapperRow.wrapperExpand {height:100%;}
.this-wont-expand-to-100-percent-in-IE {height:100%;}
```

The HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="wrapperRow">This is the header</div>

<div class="wrapperRow wrapperExpand">
<div class="this-wont-expand-to-100-percent-in-IE">
This is the content
</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapperRow">This is the footer</div>

</div>
</body>
```

**CodePen: http://cdpn.io/ILisk**

***THE PROBLEM:***

Well, the problem is this works just fine in Chrome and Firefox... however it does **NOT** work in **IE 9 or lower** (not sure if it does in IE 10). The 'wrapperRow wrapperExpand' div does have it's height set to an absolute height of 100%, which is the parent of the 'this-wont-expand-to-100-percent-in-IE' and that is also set to 100%. I don't understand why this doesn't work. Does anyone have a solution or work around to make that inner child div (the 'this-wont-expand-to-100-percent-in-IE' one) match the height of it's parent? (the 'wrapperRow wrapperExpand' one)

I'm starting to think that it's just not possible in IE... at least not without using java-script perhaps... unfortunately I'm really not that familiar with that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

*Web browsers often tries to fix your bad-coding, but only smarter ones will succeed!*

When you use `table` display type such as `table`, `table-row` for some elements, It's supposed to use `table-cell` for inner elements too. That's what you've forgot:

```
.this-will-expand-to-100-percent-in-IE {
  display: table-cell;
  height:100%;
}
```

Here is the **[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/hashem/full/wFyul)**.

By the way, in this case, I'd prefer to use [Ryan Fait's Sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) (instead of using a CSS table layout). You could also find a snippet on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/).

Comment: Yes but then it goes as wide as the parent, which unfortunately I don't want. I wanted the "wrapper" to be 100% for design reasons (mostly because I want a 100% wide menu bar and footer)... I don't want the content area to be 100%, but rather 978px in width and centered. I know I didn't mention this so it was unfair for me to expect you to know, but still that's the situation I'm in.

Comment: Also as far as Ryan's Fair's sticky footer, it is not variable in height... which is why I can't use it. I need it variable in height because its for a template for Joomla and the content in the footer can change height.

Comment: Just for clarification, What do you mean by `The 'wrapperRow wrapperExpand' div does have it's height set to an absolute height of 100%`? It has a `green` class right? and the background was green as well before. and one more thing, what do you mean by `it goes as wide as the parent`? as wide or as tall? because currently every division has a `100%` width.

Comment: I'm sorry it does keep the width, it was the margin: 0 auto; that stopped working when you turned it into a table-cell. I need it to be a regular div... just inside the 'table' divs. Is there no way to get a div to expand to 100% height of the parent table cell?

Comment: You said `Does anyone have a solution or work around to make that inner child div match the height of it's parent?`. Please **Note** that the *parent* has a height of `100%`. so when the inner match the height of its parent, it'll has a height of `100%` too.

Comment: @TCDFactory please provide another example on CodePen or somewhere else which indicates the real situation you have, and let me help :)

Comment: Actually I was right about the width as well... if you set a div to "display:table-cell" it will be as wide as the parent div it is in regardless if you tell it to be a specific width. The only exception to this of course is if there is more then one "table-cell" next to each other... but they must always add up to 100%. I want a fixed width that I can center on screen. If you are still unsure what I mean I can setup a CodePen example.

Comment: @TCDFactory, Check the CodePen Demo again please: http://codepen.io/hashem/pen/wFyul Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @TCDFactory For the width issue, I should say that it is the expected behavior of cells, table cells SHOULD take all width of its parent. you can create a table-cell element, then inside that, create your centered division, as I did.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36178/discussion-between-hashem-qolami-and-tcd-factory)

Comment: Yes that's what I am trying to do. I have figured out how to get it that far... only now the problem is that in IE the 100% height div element pushes the footer off the page no matter what (even when there isn't content pushing it down). It does NOT display this behavior in Chrome or FF.

Comment: It seems as if there is no way to get the inner element to be a fixed width AND be 100% height AND not push the footer off the bottom of the page in IE at the same time. :( At least not that I can see.

Comment: come in chat area please :)